# Where does SQL output values when OUTPUT clause is used in PHP string variable?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am trying to retrieve an auto-incremented value that is created upon insertion. This ID value will be used in a SELECT statement later, so it would be nice to know what it is when I insert instead of writing another query. The problem is that I don't know where OUTPUT clause outputs it. The query is in the form of a PHP string variable.

I'm new to SQL and PHP, so I'm not really sure what to try. I just need some help understanding.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Table1 (orderNumber, revisionNumber, creationDate...)"
. " OUTPUT Inserted.ID"
. " VALUES (blah, blah, blah...)";
execute_query($query);
```

Comment: what is . " OUTPUT Inserted.ID" ?

Comment: you want retrieve an auto-incremented value that is created upon insertion. ?????

Comment: @MohitKumar I did some reading on the Microsoft SQL Server docs and it says it's supposed to output the value ID that was created when the values are inserted into the table.

Comment: @MohitKumar yeah exactly

Comment: What are you using to execute the query? Is it PDO, or an sqlsrv_ function?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I can't remember the exact functions that I'm using since I've just been using the function that was created when I joined, but they are sqlsrv_ functions for sure. I think one of them was sqlsrv_fetch_array ?? And then each row is saved to an array

Comment: @bemisjo92 I'm not super familiar with sqlsrv_ but from what I've read PHP doesn't appear to have a way to access the output of OUTPUT. It might be possible by specifying an output [parameter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php#refsect1-function.sqlsrv-query-parameters), but regardless I don't think it's something you'll be able to get at without getting into the `execute_query` function.

Comment: If you're on SQL Server, why not use `INSERT INTO Table1 (orderNumber, revisionNumber, creationDate...) VALUES (blah, blah, blah...); select [Id]=scope_identity();` The `OUTPUT` keyword is intended to insert its column values into another table (@table variable, #temp table or user table).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning scope_identity() worked perfectly in the SQL Server console, but when I used it with the execute_query function that was written for me, nothing populates the array variable that should be populated. I ended up just writing another query to get the ID based on the name, but had this worked it would've been much more useful.